# PPCG equivalent to http://stackoverflow.com/jobs

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, policy, advertising

[Dyalog](http://dyalog.com)'s APL team is [looking to hire](http://dyalog.com/careers.htm), and we are more interested in golfers than [regular programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs), as the former are more likely to have the right mindset.

Since codegolf.stackexchange.com/jobs doesn't exist, could it be created?

Comment: What do you need code golfers for? Not that I disapprove of your initiative, but it's a bit odd, is all.

Comment: @ГригорийПерельман Well, not that [we need code *golfers*](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11755/43319) per se, but rather that many golfers are open to non-traditional coding and methods, and may not shy away from languages that mainly use single-character (non-English-letter) primitives.

Comment: Why not use stackoverflow jobs and sort applicants by PPCG rep?

Comment: @NonlinearFruit You mean by manually looking applicant's up, no? Well, the idea here was exposure specifically to golfers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think an equivalent to the Jobs program on SO is really appropriate for our site. For most of the jobs, they'd be the same ones advertised on SO, so it would be better to keep the postings consolidated there.

For your specific example, a community ad may be a better option. If not, mentioning it in The Nineteenth Byte will give it some good exposure.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that community ads were for "non-community" too, and I certainly thought I'd be banned from the chat if I made commercial announcements there.

Comment: @Adám Community ads are for the community. I don't really participate much in the ad creation process, so I'm not 100% certain if they would be appropriate for advertising that your company is hiring, but if they are, it would be a good choice IMO. In chat, it could possibly be viewed as spam, but personally I wouldn't flag it, validate a flag, or kick you for it (and I'd imagine the other mods/ROs wouldn't, either). It's helpful and constructive, so there's no issue in my eyes.

Comment: Thank you for this. As I entered PPCG from a commercial side, I have been trying to be very careful about things like these.

Comment: On the Nineteenth Byte, things disappear into the archive relatively quickly. What would be an acceptable repeat rate, if any?

Comment: @Adám probably every couple days, and at different times of day. Consider: most people are in TNB regularly, i.e. every day from 9-5 while they work. If they aren't interested once, they're unlikely to be a second time. However, the people who work 9-5 in the UK or in Germany may be interested (and assuming there's no language barrier), so a post 12 hours later may be interesting to them.

Comment: However, since it's on the starboard now, I'd definitely wait until it drops off + another couple days.